# EclipseLink - Invalid query key [latestVersionFlag] in expression

Tags: java, eclipselink

I just upgraded from Toplink to EclipseLink and am running in to this error

Exception [EclipseLink-6015] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException Exception Description: Invalid query key [latestVersionFlag] in expression. Query: ReadAllQuery(name="bookingVersionCollection" referenceClass=BookingVersion )

My descriptor looks like this

```
OneToManyMapping bookingVersionCollectionMapping = new OneToManyMapping();
bookingVersionCollectionMapping.setAttributeName("bookingVersionCollection");
bookingVersionCollectionMapping.setReferenceClass(BookingVersion.class);
bookingVersionCollectionMapping.useTransparentCollection();
bookingVersionCollectionMapping.useCollectionClass(IndirectList.class);
bookingVersionCollectionMapping.addAscendingOrdering("bookingVersionID");
bookingVersionCollectionMapping.addTargetForeignKeyFieldName("RS_BOOKINGVERSION.RS_BKG_ID", "RS_BOOKING.RS_BKG_ID");
bookingVersionCollectionMapping.setSelectionCriteria(bookingVersionCollectionMapping.buildSelectionCriteria()
    .and(expBuilder.get("latestVersionFlag").equal(ResConstants.FLAG_YES)));
descriptor.addMapping(bookingVersionCollectionMapping);
```

I also have a mapping for BookingVersion class that has the mapping for that field

```
DirectToFieldMapping latestVersionFlagMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
latestVersionFlagMapping.setAttributeName("latestVersionFlag");
latestVersionFlagMapping.setFieldName("RS_BOOKINGVERSION.LATESTVERSIONFLAG");
descriptor.addMapping(latestVersionFlagMapping);
```

And inside the Java poco object of BookingVersion.java that field looks like this..

```
private char latestVersionFlag = ResConstants.FLAG_YES;
```

Any ideas? This code worked in Toplink, so not sure what's going on.

Comment: When are you adding the bookingVersionCollectionMapping, and where is the exception being thrown from?  I am guessing, but seems like the expression set in the bookingVersionCollectionMapping is processed before everything else is completed, and the latestVersionFlagMapping doesn't yet have a query key.  You might need to add the selectionCriteria to the bookingVersionCollectionMapping using a descriptor customizer, so that it gets added after everything else is done being processed

Comment: Could you add the complete stacktrace (if you still have it) so that readers can compare it to other questions and EclipseLink issues. This might be discussed at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=466581.

Answer (score 1):

Well, by changing

```
bookingVersionCollectionMapping.setSelectionCriteria(bookingVersionCollectionMapping.buildSelectionCriteria()
    .and(expBuilder.get("latestVersionFlag").equal(ResConstants.FLAG_YES)));
```

to

```
bookingVersionCollectionMapping.setSelectionCriteria(bookingVersionCollectionMapping.buildSelectionCriteria()
      .and(expBuilder.getField("RS_BOOKINGVERSION.LATESTVERSIONFLAG").equal(ResConstants.FLAG_YES)));
```

seems to work..... still not sure why, but thought I would post for anyone else!

Comment: Thanks! We upgraded from 2.5.2 to 2.6.1 eclipselink and were having intermittent failures with this error. Using the getField instead of get method solved it.